# Python - part of line out of place in file

Tags: python-2.7, text-manipulation

I wrote a script to search in some files where in my pipeline sequences were eliminated. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

q = open('eg-not-sec.bait').readlines()
tm = open('eg_tm0_res').readlines()
ph = open('eg_ph01_res').readlines()
secp = open('eg_secp_res').readlines()
tp = open('eg_tp_res').readlines()
ps = open('eg_ps_res').readlines()
gpi = open('eg_es_final_ids').readlines()
nf = open('eg_elim-test', 'a')


for line in q:

    if line not in tm:
        nf.writelines('%sTMHMM\t'%line)

    elif line not in ph:
        nf.writelines('%sPH\t'%line)

    elif line not in secp:
        nf.writelines('%sSECP\t'%line)

    elif line not in tp:
        nf.writelines('%sTP\t'%line)

    elif line not in ps:
        nf.writelines('%sPS\t'%line)

    elif line not in gpi:
        nf.writelines('%sGPI\t'%line)

nf.close()
```

It would be working perfectly if wasn't for a detail: the sequence ID for the last line is in the first line, and the identification for where it was eliminated is in last line alone, Like this:

```
EgrG_000049700.1
PH  EgrG_000055800.1
PH  EgrG_000133800.1
PH  EgrG_000221600.1
PH  EgrG_000324200.1
PH  EgrG_000342900.1
PH  EgrG_000391800.1
PH  EgrG_000406000.1
PH  EgrG_000428150.1
TMHMM   EgrG_000430700.1
PH  EgrG_000477400.1
PH  EgrG_000498000.1
PH  EgrG_000502700.1
TMHMM   EgrG_000521200.1
PH  EgrG_000566700.1
PH  EgrG_000633500.1
PH  EgrG_000690700.1
PH  EgrG_000709300.1
PH  EgrG_000823900.1
PH  EgrG_000907100.1
PH  EgrG_000925400.1
PH  EgrG_000974700.1
PH  EgrG_001061400.1
PH  EgrG_001081300.1
PH  EgrG_001136900.1
PH  EgrG_001148800.1
PH  EgrG_002005100.1
PH  EgrG_002026400.1
PH  EgrG_002058200.1
PH
```

It's simple to solve manually just copying the 'PH' in last line and pasting it on first line before the sequence ID, but I'd like to know how to solve this in my code and I'm not figuring out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readlines()` method leaves the newlines at the end of each line in the returned list.  So let's take this line of code for example...

```
    nf.writelines('%sPH\t'%line)
```

This outputs one of your lines, complete with newline at the end.  It then puts "PH" and a tab *on the next line*.  And since it outputs no newline of its own, whatever you write next will appear on the same line as the PH.

I think you want something like this:

```
    nf.write("PH\t%s" % line)
```

to put things in the right order.  Also note the use of `write` (which outputs a single string) instead of `writelines` (which outputs a *sequence* of strings): you were basically telling Python to output each character of your string individually rather than all at once.

Comment: Sorry, man, it's not working too. It's giving me the same result as before. :/
I've changed all `writelines()` for `write()` and all `readlines()` for `read()` and it keeps giving me exactly the same result, with the PH alone in last line.
I guess I'll have to live with this :/ hehe

Comment: ``readlines()`` was correct; with ``read()`` you've got the entire file as a single 'line'.  "PH alone in the last line" indicates that you didn't fix the fundamental problem, which is that you were putting PH after instead of before the '%s'.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Now it worked! Thanks! But I've had to keep `.readlines()`, with just `read()` it gave me nothing. So now it's with `.readlines()` and `.write()` instead of `writelines()` and with the change in the of PH and %s you told me. Thanks again!